# how to call one function in different in same file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

this is my first function

```
exports.users=function(req,res){
    var sql="SELECT * FROM table";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            //console.log()
            res.render('user',{data:result});
        }
    })

}
```

this is my second function

```
exports.deleteuser=function(req,res){
    console.log(req.params)
    users();//gives error
};
```

this is my app.js file

```
app.get('/adduser',company.users);
app.get('/deleteuser/:email',function(req,res){

    var email=req.params.email;
    var sql="DELETE FROM appuser where email='"+ email +"'";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,res){
        if(err)
            console.log(err)
        else
            {
                alert("deleted")
            }
    });
    res.render('adduser');
})
```

what i want is to call users in deleteuser..
Both are in same file..Im using ejs,nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare it within module

```
function users(req,res){
    var sql="SELECT * FROM table";
    connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            //console.log()
            res.render('user',{data:result});
        }
    })

}

module.exports.users = users;

module.exports.deleteuser = function(req, res) {
  users() // accessible here
  // or
  module.exports.users(req, res) // w/o changing your original declaration
}
```

Also you need to pass request and response from `deleteuser` to `users`

Comment: no i cant do this as users function is called in another file also.. see the edits i have done

Comment: @primo "no i cant do this as users function is called in another file also" - and? You could still call the function as you did before.